# Progress bar for data collection outside of Shiny server

Tags: r, shiny, progress-bar

I have a Shiny app that pulls data from SQL upon opening the app.  The data set has a large number of observations and is added to daily.  Currently it takes about 16 seconds to load the data.  I'd like to add a progress bar to show users that the app is in fact running.  I have looked up progress bars such as that [here.](https://gallery.shinyapps.io/085-progress/) However, everything I have found is within the server function.  Currently, I am pulling the data only once outside of the function, then subsetting it (based on user inputs) within the function. Is there a way to do create a progress bar for this?

My other thought was to create something that appears when the app loads and disappears once the data has been fully retrieved but I do not know where to start for that.

Comment: Progress bar wouldn't be that useful as you really dont know how long the data will take to query, it might take a few mins for example so displaying percentage complete is cumbersome. May I suggest you look into `shinycssloaders` package which has a lot of waiting spinners you can add to your project https://github.com/andrewsali/shinycssloaders

Comment: @PorkChop I will give it a try, but I am uncertain as to where in my code I would put this

Comment: in the ui, straight after the widget